# How do I make a gulp function run in series? (gulp-download)

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I've been trying to set up functions to download and then install frameworks into my development workflow with gulp-download. Every time I run gulp-download in series, it always runs last, so the function tries to move the files, then they download.

I tried to use merge and run this in a single function, then split it and used a task in series to run it. Neither way is successful.

```
// DOWNLOAD BOOTSTRAP
function downloadBootstrap(cb) {
  download('https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v4.0.0/bootstrap-4.0.0-dist.zip')
    .pipe(unzip())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('downloads/bootstrap'));
  cb();
}

// INSTALL BOOTSTRAT
function installBootstrap(cb) {

  var css = gulp.src('downloads/bootstrap/css/*.{min.css,min.css.map}')
    .pipe(dest('_developer/2-css/0-frameworks/bootstrap'))

  var js = gulp.src('downloads/bootstrap/js/*.{min.js,min.js.map}')
  .pipe(dest('_developer/3-js/0-frameworks/bootstrap'))

  var clear = gulp.src('downloads/bootstrap', {read: false, allowEmpty: true})
  .pipe(clean())

  return merge(css, js, clear); // Combined src
  cb();
}

gulp.task('bootstrap', gulp.series('downloadBootstrap', 'installBootstrap'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you only call the callback function when your task is complete. Inside `download`, the function call returning doesn't mean the download has finished. However, since you're using a pipeline here, you can eliminate the callback parameter altogether. (On an unrelated note, I would avoid having two functions named download.)

```
// DOWNLOAD BOOTSTRAP
function download() {
  return download('https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v4.0.0/bootstrap-4.0.0-dist.zip')
    .pipe(unzip())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('downloads/bootstrap'));
}
```

Returning the stream will ensure that the stream has been fully processed before the next task continues. Also, you can just remove the callback from your install function since it will never actually be used. (Nothing runs after your function returns.)

Comment: Ah, just got your comment now I've refreshed the page. I re-wrote install function using returns instead of vars. When doing this, I decided to try adding a return to the download!

I changed that function to add a second 'download' for the case of this code snippet, as I was just using initials as I kept other versions of my code haha.

Thanks for your explanation though. So a return is the same as a callback in terms of functionality?

Comment: That depends what you're returning. If you return a promise or a stream, there's no need to explicitly call the callback function. Gulp will take care of that by itself. You could use another `pipe` on the end to call the callback, but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out, I just had to add return to the download lol. Now I have the download finishing before it moves onto the install, but now only the css is migrated, the js remains and the clean isn't running. I had these working before.

```
gulp.task("bootstrap", gulp.series(downloadBootstrap, installBootstrap));

function downloadBootstrap() {

  return download('https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v4.0.0/bootstrap-4.0.0-dist.zip')
    .pipe(unzip())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('downloads/bootstrap'));

}

function installBootstrap() {

  return gulp.src('downloads/bootstrap/css/*.{min.css,min.css.map}') // Gather [developer] css files
    .pipe(gulp.dest('_developer/2-css/0-frameworks/bootstrap')) // Deliver css files to [build]

  return gulp.src('downloads/bootstrap/js/*.{min.js,min.js.map}') // Gather [developer] css files
    .pipe(gulp.dest('_developer/3-js/0-frameworks/bootstrap')) // Deliver css files to [build]

  return gulp.src('downloads/bootstrap', { allowEmpty: true })
    .pipe(clean());

}
```

Comment: Revert your `installBootstrap` task to how you had it before.